# How to set select all data up to data_upload_max_number_fields (example 500) in django admin listing page

Tags: python, django, select, django-admin, overriding

First of all sorry if is there any question already please let me know that because I am fresh in this community

And thanks in advance for your valuable responses

In the below screenshot in Django admin, How can I override the select all 1005 with some custom number like select up to 500. As you know data_upload_max_number_fields has only a 1000 limit but I don't want to increase the limit every time. Because it might be possible I have 100000 data then how much will increase the

data_upload_max_number_fields in django settings.
So is there any way that I can override this select all thing to less than the upload max field

for example select all up to first 500 data

[image: Selecting all 1005 and deleting throw error]

[image: this shows all 1005 selected]

I don't want like the default one shown in the 2nd image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there does not seem to be a direct attribute/method to change the max limit but what you can do is set a custom value in the 'list_per_page' attribute of the ModelAdmin class admin.py like below:

```
class MyAppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    list_per_page = 500

    class Meta:
        model = MyApp
```

The default value of *list_per_page* is 100 hence now after modifying it you can directly select all 500(in your case) at once per page and perform the requisite operation.

Comment: No, I don't mean that I want the customisation in select all 1005 one
per_page 100 is okay